# Simplifying $z^3 e^{i\pi/3} +1 = 0 $

Tags: complex-numbers

> Given $$z^3 e^{i\pi/3} +1 = 0 $$
>       We have, $ z^3 = e^{i2\pi/3} $

I get

$$ e^{i\pi/3}z^3 = -1 $$

$$ z^3 = \frac{-1}{e^{i\pi/3}} $$
$$ z^3 = -e^{i2\pi/3} $$
instead

May I know how did we arrived at $z^3$ ?

Comment: because $e^{\pi i}=-1$

Comment: @Integrator Yes. I thought that $−1e^{−iπ/3} = −e^{2π/3}$

Comment: @Integrator Apparently it does not work. I would have to invert the sign of $-1$ too. For example $-5e^{-i5\pi/7}$ = $5e^{i2\pi/7}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html)

> $$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

put $\theta=\pi$
to get

> $$e^{i\pi}=-1$$

$$e^{i\pi/3}z^3 +1 = 0$$

$$e^{i\pi/3}z^3 =-1$$
$$e^{i\pi/3}z^3 =e^{i\pi}$$

$$z^3 =\frac{e^{i\pi}}{e^{i\pi/3}}=e^{i(\pi-\pi/3)}=e^{i2\pi/3}$$
And you can also verify using same formula that whatever you got is not wrong it's just different way to represent it!

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

One of the most beautiful formula in mathematics is $$\Large e^{i \pi}+1=0$$ So for your equation, $$e^{i\pi/3}z^3 +1 = e^{i\pi/3}z^3 -e^{i \pi}=0$$

I am sure that you can take from here.